# Fetching multiple data in JSON format with PHP, from multiple text file with a single AJAX POST (array)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to fetch multiple data from multiple text file with a single AJAX POST, so that the HTTP requests/posts can be minimized and web page process smoothly on low bandwidth also.

Here is my code:

HTML/jQuery:

```
 var time = 0;
 var refreshTime = ''; // refreshTime = setInterval -> refresh()
 var arr = ['one@one.com','two@two.com','three@three.com']  //for example, I use only 3 emails

 function refresh(){
   $.ajax({
     url: 'fetch.php?action=detail",
     type: 'POST',
     data: 'time='+time+'&to='+arr+'&from=forme@demo.com', //sending emails as `to`, emails separated with `,`. `to` and `from` is the name of `dir` and `txt` file.
     dataType: 'json',
     cache: false,
     success: function(response){
       if(response.length) {
         for(var i in response) {
           alert(response[i]);
         }
       }
     },
     error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
       alert(textStatus+"-"+errorThrown);
     }
   });
 }
```

PHP:

```
 define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);
 include('functions.php');
 header('Content-Type: application/json');
 $data = array();

 switch($_GET['action']) {

 case 'detail':   
   $from = $_POST['from'];
   $to = explode(',', $_POST['to']); //exploding the `,`
   foreach($to as $key){  
     // check `dir` and than check `text file`
     if(!is_dir("details/".$key)&&(!file_exists("details/".$key."/".$from.".txt") || 0 == filesize("details/".$key."/".$from.".txt"))){
       $file = "details/".$from."/".$key.".txt";
     }else{
       $file = "details/".$key."/".$from.".txt";
     }

     // when I used `data[] = $file;` here and remove all below code, than it alerts txt file names.


     // I think that the problem started from here

     $arr = file($file);

     if(!$_POST['time']){$_POST['time'] = 0;}
     foreach($arr as $row) {
       $aTemp = null;
       list($aTemp['time'], $aTemp['date'], $aTemp['fromname'], $aTemp['to'], $aTemp['msg']) = explode('|', $row);
       if($aTemp['msg'] AND $aTemp['time'] > $_POST['time']){ // checking the time, if `POST` time is lower than the `$aTemp['time']` then add the contents to `$data`
           $data[] = $aTemp;
         }
       }
     }
   break;

 }

 echo json_encode($data);
```

`firebug` shows `[]` response.

And this is the working code if I send single email with ajax POST to do the same thing

(The demerit of this is: if there are 4 emails, then I have to initialize it 4 times and it send 4 query - more emails, more queries - burden on bandwidth).

```
 var time = 0, refreshTime = '';

 function refresh(to){
 $.ajax({
   url: 'fetch.php?action=detail",
   type: 'POST',
   data: 'time='+time+'&to='+to+'&from=forme@demo.com', 
   dataType: 'json',
   cache: false,
   success: function(response){
     if(response.length) {
       for(var i in response) {
         alert(response[i]);
       }
     }
   },
   error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
     alert(textStatus+"-"+errorThrown);
   }
 });
 }


 case 'detail':   
   $from = $_POST['from'];
   $to = $_POST['to'];
   if(!is_dir("details/".$to)&&(!file_exists("details/".$to."/".$from.".txt") || 0 == filesize("details/".$to."/".$from.".txt"))){
     $file = "details/".$from."/".$to.".txt";
   }else{
     $file = "details/".$to."/".$from.".txt";
   }
   $arr = file($file);
   if(!$_POST['time']){$_POST['time'] = 0;}
   foreach($arr as $row) {
     $aTemp = null;
     list($aTemp['time'], $aTemp['date'], $aTemp['fromname'], $aTemp['to'], $aTemp['msg']) = explode('|', $row);
     if($aTemp['msg'] AND $aTemp['time'] > $_POST['time']){ 
         $data[] = $aTemp;
      }
    }
  }
  break;
```

Any suggestions or solution for this?

**Update: closest to the answer, but not perfect:**

PHP:

```
 case 'view':     
   $from = $_POST['from'];
   $to = explode(',', $_POST['to']);
   foreach($to as $key){
     if(!is_dir("details/".$to)&&(!file_exists("details/".$to."/".$from.".txt") || 0 == filesize("details/".$to."/".$from.".txt"))){
       $file = "details/".$from."/".$to.".txt";
     }else{
       $file = "details/".$to."/".$from.".txt";
     }
     $arr = file($file);
     if(!$_POST['time']){$_POST['time'] = 0;}
     foreach($arr as $row) {
       $aTemp = null;
       list($aTemp['time'], $aTemp['date'], $aTemp['fromname'], $aTemp['to'], $aTemp['msg']) = explode('|', $row);
       if($aTemp['msg'] AND $aTemp['time'] > $_POST['time']){
         $n[] = $aTemp;
       }
     }
     $data[$key] = $n;
   }
 break;
```

This code returns (`firebug console result`):

```
 {
    "one@one.com":[
      {"msg":"hi","to":"one@one.com","fromname":"one","date":"April 1, 2014","time":"1396376996"},
      {"msg":"...","to":"...","fromname":"...","date":"...","time":"..."},
      ...
    ],
    "two@two.com":[
       {"msg":"...","to":"...","fromname":"...","date":"...","time":"..."},
       ....
    ]
 }
```

Now I'm unable to guess that how to manipulate/use it in jQuery. Something like:

```
 var arr = ['one@one.com','two@two.com',...];

 success: function(response){
   if(response.length) {
     for(var i in arr){
       var a = arr[i];
       alert(response.a);
     }
   }
 },
```

So that it alerts the array value based on `arr = [...]`.

UPDATE: SOLUTION (`jQ part`):

```
 for(var i in response){
   console.log(i);
   for(var j in response[i]){
     console.log(response[i][j]);
   }
 }
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really clear what your problem is. If it is the Javascript part and you want to iterate over all messages, you can do it like this:

```
success: function(response){
    for (var from in response){
        for (var i = 0, l = response[from].length; i < l; i++) {
            var msg = response[from][i];
            console.log(msg.fromname + ": " + msg.msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Or is the PHP output not what you want?

Comment: thnks for replying, but your code does nothing. `no log in the console. totally blank`. but I got the idea from your replying.

thnks

Comment: Oops, needed to remove the outer `if (response.length)` as you get an object, not an array. Edited the answer, so that it now should work.

Comment: Thanks but you are few seconds late :)
anyways I'm selecting your answer as a perfect answer bcz my solution is based on it.